# Meteor not connecting to external mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have set the MONGO_URL environment variable, but still meteor starts its own mongodb server.
It shows no error message.
How can I use the external mongodb ?

```
xxx@xxx-WSG68F55W8-0007:~/development/ocd_chn/ui$ echo $MONGO_URL
mongodb://10.145.4.148:27017/meteor
xxx@xxx-WSG68F55W8-0007:~/development/ocd_chn/ui$ sudo meteor 
Unable to update package catalog (are you offline?)

[[[[[ ~/development/ocd_chn/ui ]]]]]          

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

The mongodb is running on the 10.145.4.148:27017 machine, and i'm able to access it on robomongo

Comment: Did you remember to `export` your variable? Also it might be easier to set the variable right in front of your `meteor` call.

Comment: Yes i did set that variable. xxx@xxx-WSG68F55W8-0007:~/development/ocd_chn/ui$ echo $MONGO_URL
mongodb://10.145.4.148:27017/meteor

Comment: It looks like you set `MONGO_URL` in your own shell environment, and then ran `sudo` to start Meteor (which would spawn a new shell environment as the root user). I would suggest running Meteor without sudo (and fixing your permissions if it needs to run with sudo at the moment). If the environment variable is set in the same shell session, it should be detected properly.